# Python 3.5 Weird Bug with parsing JSON

Tags: python, json, parsing

When I parse a long piece of JSON on my computer it just returns an empty string but whenever I test it on another computer it works perfectly

I'm not too sure why this doesn't work on this specific computer.

[image: On this specific computer]

Proof it works on this online IDE: http://ideone.com/kdIHDT

The code I attempted on both my computer and the online ide:

```
import json
print(json.loads("""{"userdata":{"name":"VerySmalls","id":99634337,"total":{"rap":30182,"value":30182},"rank":{"value":"9341","rap":"9109"},"state":1},"inventory":[{"name":"Modern Military Santa","image":"http:\/\/t1.rbxcdn.com\/c892a785ef99e6209fa271eb9189dfc2","link":"\/Modern-Military-Santa-item?id=19107800","id":"19107800","serial":[1450],"serialcount":2500,"rap":"689","value":"689","uaid":[146134914],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Labor Day 2009 Gear Goggles","image":"http:\/\/t6.rbxcdn.com\/56b1b78e5ebe7cb2191e8f8a23bccdce","link":"\/Labor-Day-2009-Gear-Goggles-item?id=15595872","id":"15595872","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"660","value":"660","uaid":[72182462],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"The Riddling Skull","image":"http:\/\/t7.rbxcdn.com\/019650255c70c9a5d56ae47ee05b3f98","link":"\/The-Riddling-Skull-item?id=4765718","id":"4765718","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"651","value":"651","uaid":[12815820,12935452],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Spec Alpha Biograft Energy Sword","image":"http:\/\/t3.rbxcdn.com\/d405878e9ba010b9d1dc1face8241b9e","link":"\/Spec-Alpha-Biograft-Energy-Sword-item?id=11999235","id":"11999235","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"609","value":"609","uaid":[42660150],"type":1,"demand":-1},{"name":"The Moon","image":"http:\/\/t4.rbxcdn.com\/5df49cfaa1588ddd244ab90d6712c0c2","link":"\/The-Moon-item?id=7319168","id":"7319168","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"594","value":"594","uaid":[22027708],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Blue Winter Cap","image":"http:\/\/t4.rbxcdn.com\/24d0505d3dcd164442f73a4dcfd6eaa5","link":"\/Blue-Winter-Cap-item?id=1309918","id":"1309918","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"565","value":"565","uaid":[16051903],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Black Paintball Mask","image":"http:\/\/t1.rbxcdn.com\/80e9a0005435291775693b931115e50c","link":"\/Black-Paintball-Mask-item?id=9254521","id":"9254521","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"543","value":"543","uaid":[33187485,29667716,29603440],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Your Head, a Marshmallow Floating in Hot Chocolate","image":"http:\/\/t1.rbxcdn.com\/c06fb0ee32bc7a1fffa0809eaee66e61","link":"\/Your-Head-a-Marshmallow-Floating-in-Hot-Chocolate-item?id=19395368","id":"19395368","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"510","value":"510","uaid":[150173168],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Tixsplosion","image":"http:\/\/t4.rbxcdn.com\/20829dba1f93f846ca59b669c384829f","link":"\/Tixsplosion-item?id=6512277","id":"6512277","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"504","value":"504","uaid":[19119752,19102247,19103142,19104606],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Cool Snowman Head","image":"http:\/\/t2.rbxcdn.com\/8071c4639889ade76bcdedc3a9e9dd19","link":"\/Cool-Snowman-Head-item?id=5832475","id":"5832475","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"499","value":"499","uaid":[17272992,18706598],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Turkey's Vengeance Sword","image":"http:\/\/t6.rbxcdn.com\/7beafca5648a20acfb38e3bd106ae134","link":"\/Turkeys-Vengeance-Sword-item?id=65969704","id":"65969704","serial":[1124],"serialcount":1500,"rap":"377","value":"377","uaid":[739975432],"type":1,"demand":-1},{"name":"Thought Fortress","image":"http:\/\/t1.rbxcdn.com\/f6e3ed0037e9f1496f9030f762e1717a","link":"\/Thought-Fortress-item?id=6548058","id":"6548058","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"361","value":"361","uaid":[19282149],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Annoying Elf: Finsurf","image":"http:\/\/t2.rbxcdn.com\/3f4305d70878fdb390f0a79c9922f293","link":"\/Annoying-Elf-Finsurf-item?id=67798397","id":"67798397","serial":[1007],"serialcount":2011,"rap":"308","value":"308","uaid":[766659385],"type":1,"demand":-1},{"name":"Racing Helmet","image":"http:\/\/t2.rbxcdn.com\/da455ee0b1b27ecb823346b17fd5e59f","link":"\/Racing-Helmet-item?id=6379764","id":"6379764","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"274","value":"274","uaid":[18531100],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Sk9r Boi","image":"http:\/\/t6.rbxcdn.com\/f42da6174bbd7465c0445ddc0b831018","link":"\/Sk9r-Boi-item?id=16412796","id":"16412796","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"253","value":"253","uaid":[424151666],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Mysterious Witch Pumpkin","image":"http:\/\/t1.rbxcdn.com\/ec2bb1a662c370c27338224309acd12b","link":"\/Mysterious-Witch-Pumpkin-item?id=313544522","id":"313544522","serial":[1871],"serialcount":2500,"rap":"244","value":"244","uaid":[2988731974],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"2014 Shades","image":"http:\/\/t3.rbxcdn.com\/19a0efcd98b1b0c46f260d295f8267d9","link":"\/2014-Shades-item?id=140469106","id":"140469106","serial":[1034],"serialcount":2014,"rap":"238","value":"238","uaid":[1645721318],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Steampunk Tricorn","image":"http:\/\/t6.rbxcdn.com\/ce534efedf3f74cc0e536b15b2a81a1d","link":"\/Steampunk-Tricorn-item?id=215718576","id":"215718576","serial":[1012],"serialcount":2000,"rap":"223","value":"223","uaid":[2395346229],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Slimy Eye Ball Top Hat","image":"http:\/\/t1.rbxcdn.com\/e4c9087fab69a9ea572624bcfbddfdab","link":"\/Slimy-Eye-Ball-Top-Hat-item?id=182774977","id":"182774977","serial":[2597],"serialcount":5000,"rap":"210","value":"210","uaid":[2106409006],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Turkey Tie 2012","image":"http:\/\/t7.rbxcdn.com\/2c3bdc43ad85630730f9165a559177e0","link":"\/Turkey-Tie-2012-item?id=98421766","id":"98421766","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"210","value":"210","uaid":[1137346603],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Pumpkin Pi","image":"http:\/\/t6.rbxcdn.com\/810d9cf7b96efa1d62991801eaebee93","link":"\/Pumpkin-Pi-item?id=16986805","id":"16986805","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"176","value":"176","uaid":[189888097],"type":1,"demand":-1},{"name":"Magic Wizard Owl","image":"http:\/\/t6.rbxcdn.com\/626d2b5fedb698324f22f9a294940b4a","link":"\/Magic-Wizard-Owl-item?id=315550913","id":"315550913","serial":[477,931,1482],"serialcount":3000,"rap":"170","value":"170","uaid":[3006772139,3006784599,3006824769],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Summertime 2009 R&R&R","image":"http:\/\/t3.rbxcdn.com\/3ff980e7298051214c725331af9ee51d","link":"\/Summertime-2009-R-R-R-item?id=13334984","id":"13334984","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"165","value":"165","uaid":[49133256],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Shooting Star 2014","image":"http:\/\/t0.rbxcdn.com\/4c082e32dc4b9b8bec98b58d927eb1ff","link":"\/Shooting-Star-2014-item?id=161211433","id":"161211433","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"153","value":"153","uaid":[1871290794],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Monster Bowtie","image":"http:\/\/t5.rbxcdn.com\/b39cb4e24907a7309675e625f692f60e","link":"\/Monster-Bowtie-item?id=315549086","id":"315549086","serial":[387,748,1295,2330],"serialcount":2500,"rap":"143","value":"143","uaid":[3006934392,3006807608,3006810854,3006844776],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Fiery Egg of Egg Testing","image":"http:\/\/t3.rbxcdn.com\/72c8a089ebb7a6c8c4bc8327a4647b5c","link":"\/Fiery-Egg-of-Egg-Testing-item?id=27345567","id":"27345567","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"138","value":"138","uaid":[327610090,327755708,328533667],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Vicious Egg of Singularity","image":"http:\/\/t2.rbxcdn.com\/c71367af39b74980fca6130728c91faf","link":"\/Vicious-Egg-of-Singularity-item?id=24826853","id":"24826853","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"137","value":"137","uaid":[328459317],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Breakfast Shades","image":"http:\/\/t5.rbxcdn.com\/01e027f6a33e96c8890298f6b89c6766","link":"\/Breakfast-Shades-item?id=273965627","id":"273965627","serial":[813],"serialcount":5000,"rap":"135","value":"135","uaid":[2757300158],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Wanwood Visor","image":"http:\/\/t5.rbxcdn.com\/ba562b07ebd270646cce6e18516f9e66","link":"\/Wanwood-Visor-item?id=168167114","id":"168167114","serial":[5202],"serialcount":10000,"rap":"133","value":"133","uaid":[1941682853],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Starry Egg of the Wild Ride","image":"http:\/\/t7.rbxcdn.com\/de40c8993988e5a0afaf6eaca4a617f6","link":"\/Starry-Egg-of-the-Wild-Ride-item?id=31151864","id":"31151864","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"131","value":"131","uaid":[328265480,328398734,327760350,335477398,335436141,332296573,329771448],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Purple Steampunk Robin Hood","image":"http:\/\/t2.rbxcdn.com\/38a18019bae8e052175a341f75e40e42","link":"\/Purple-Steampunk-Robin-Hood-item?id=244160118","id":"244160118","serial":[2539,2732,5632,7472],"serialcount":10000,"rap":"129","value":"129","uaid":[2594827408,2594695995,2594691806,2594775568],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Apple Pie","image":"http:\/\/t1.rbxcdn.com\/d1db205cb18794078ba422ddd339a297","link":"\/Apple-Pie-item?id=18426536","id":"18426536","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"121","value":"121","uaid":[696861482,1597176957,1591866437,131141278],"type":1,"demand":-1},{"name":"Riptide","image":"http:\/\/t5.rbxcdn.com\/3660ae844b6e48c7cd310f77ca9f05b5","link":"\/Riptide-item?id=124472052","id":"124472052","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"119","value":"119","uaid":[1613655322,1459322629,1459513582,1467771990,1470373285,1472650839,1472875436,1476910004,1476911228,1476912283,1478076069,1605005542,1605716047,1611292449,1612258097,1613030058,1613448919,1476905748],"type":1,"demand":-1},{"name":"Valentine's Day 2011 Cap","image":"http:\/\/t6.rbxcdn.com\/b86e74e0d2841fdb427c8dc07b710289","link":"\/Valentines-Day-2011-Cap-item?id=46138556","id":"46138556","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"117","value":"117","uaid":[488489253,488399215],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"POW! To the Moon! Egg","image":"http:\/\/t6.rbxcdn.com\/30e01526803b321ed85cb94ac08b7ef2","link":"\/POW-To-the-Moon-Egg-item?id=24826737","id":"24826737","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"114","value":"114","uaid":[332253758,335427281],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"St. Patrick's Day 2012","image":"http:\/\/t6.rbxcdn.com\/415093d37f786c144287bed2d3ea5316","link":"\/St-Patricks-Day-2012-item?id=74939534","id":"74939534","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"114","value":"114","uaid":[859518263],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Dreamweaver Faberg\u00e9 Egg","image":"http:\/\/t7.rbxcdn.com\/ed1ba58fd84123529d5475063c577f40","link":"\/Dreamweaver-Faberg-Egg-item?id=102614621","id":"102614621","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"112","value":"112","uaid":[1299066294],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Halloween 2011 Paintball Cap","image":"http:\/\/t7.rbxcdn.com\/d089f3a1dd332257926c91e5dfad9057","link":"\/Halloween-2011-Paintball-Cap-item?id=61847146","id":"61847146","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"111","value":"111","uaid":[733818640,721468555,719776484],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Valentine's Day 2012 Cap","image":"http:\/\/t7.rbxcdn.com\/80c0c88c1649090100dc4f4020021bf5","link":"\/Valentines-Day-2012-Cap-item?id=72082097","id":"72082097","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"109","value":"109","uaid":[826615874],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Bolt Biter ","image":"http:\/\/t3.rbxcdn.com\/ecc4395ae166bd1f299a788ba8a47d3d","link":"\/Bolt-Biter-item?id=114385254","id":"114385254","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"108","value":"108","uaid":[1343984340],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Purple Crazy Glasses","image":"http:\/\/t0.rbxcdn.com\/6619c8a71fdaca7c7779383fe7abdf14","link":"\/Purple-Crazy-Glasses-item?id=243854130","id":"243854130","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"108","value":"108","uaid":[2580109584,2580094073,2580046902,2580007872,2579973403,2579967101,2579896153,2579776400,2579771972,2579759337,2579703781,2579674722,2579649571,2579648595,2580115531,2579824768,2580140255,2580350582,2580213356,2600744125,2593639261,2592278398,2589798845,2587450878,2580200366,2583831715,2583315006,2582130959,2581951779,2581731773,2581713334,2584076135,2581367833,2581343147,2581180991,2580884805,2580792186,2580665158,2580587946,2580492313,2580331536,2580411692,2580347551,2581392400],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Bat Tie","image":"http:\/\/t1.rbxcdn.com\/1a68c0b8a7f991c69a402822bd14f8a7","link":"\/Bat-Tie-item?id=63239668","id":"63239668","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"104","value":"104","uaid":[706325495,706337838,706339132,706327073],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Valentine's Day Cap 2014","image":"http:\/\/t1.rbxcdn.com\/4c725366cf3456ef00ea41999c08aac8","link":"\/Valentines-Day-Cap-2014-item?id=145834328","id":"145834328","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"102","value":"102","uaid":[1702982968,1704772816,1704655454,1704329398,1704142116,1703837519,1703498997,1703280181,1703027114,1706197010,1702878340,1702871064,1702810459,1702725430,1702705174,1702701882],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Red Baseball Cap","image":"http:\/\/t2.rbxcdn.com\/e7043f0de498a8d86a0dd3a2f9dda464","link":"\/Red-Baseball-Cap-item?id=1028606","id":"1028606","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"90","value":"90","uaid":[650588326,799849316,911838756,970599680,1061635619,20390155,1429627843,1689570540,2046428127,9184819,1901694246,2617525148,2201066710,2234239276,2321759816,2355999772,2472984787,2473474879,2474406223,1713281777,2503188546,2476284946,2477624042,2477717806,2493438443,1836184721,1828801218,2484030858,1750266172,2862455261,2631383132,2830069799,2813484524,2699740901,2769611946,2790486081,2771923409,1800268772],"type":0,"demand":-1}],"total_count":189}"""))
```

Comment: There is no import json in your `test.py` and yet no error is thrown, something weird in the way you run it.

Comment: It's on line 1, I just scrolled down by accident.

Comment: A good first step in debugging code is to break complex lines of code into two or more simpler lines. So, the first step would be to assign the json to a variable, and then pass the variable to the function and save the results in a variable, then pass the variable to `print`. That way you can determine which part of that statement has a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Escape your single quotes with \'

try this:

```
import json
print(json.loads("""{"userdata":{"name":"VerySmalls","id":99634337,"total":{"rap":30182,"value":30182},"rank":{"value":"9341","rap":"9109"},"state":1},"inventory":[{"name":"Modern Military Santa","image":"http:\/\/t1.rbxcdn.com\/c892a785ef99e6209fa271eb9189dfc2","link":"\/Modern-Military-Santa-item?id=19107800","id":"19107800","serial":[1450],"serialcount":2500,"rap":"689","value":"689","uaid":[146134914],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Labor Day 2009 Gear Goggles","image":"http:\/\/t6.rbxcdn.com\/56b1b78e5ebe7cb2191e8f8a23bccdce","link":"\/Labor-Day-2009-Gear-Goggles-item?id=15595872","id":"15595872","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"660","value":"660","uaid":[72182462],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"The Riddling Skull","image":"http:\/\/t7.rbxcdn.com\/019650255c70c9a5d56ae47ee05b3f98","link":"\/The-Riddling-Skull-item?id=4765718","id":"4765718","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"651","value":"651","uaid":[12815820,12935452],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Spec Alpha Biograft Energy Sword","image":"http:\/\/t3.rbxcdn.com\/d405878e9ba010b9d1dc1face8241b9e","link":"\/Spec-Alpha-Biograft-Energy-Sword-item?id=11999235","id":"11999235","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"609","value":"609","uaid":[42660150],"type":1,"demand":-1},{"name":"The Moon","image":"http:\/\/t4.rbxcdn.com\/5df49cfaa1588ddd244ab90d6712c0c2","link":"\/The-Moon-item?id=7319168","id":"7319168","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"594","value":"594","uaid":[22027708],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Blue Winter Cap","image":"http:\/\/t4.rbxcdn.com\/24d0505d3dcd164442f73a4dcfd6eaa5","link":"\/Blue-Winter-Cap-item?id=1309918","id":"1309918","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"565","value":"565","uaid":[16051903],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Black Paintball Mask","image":"http:\/\/t1.rbxcdn.com\/80e9a0005435291775693b931115e50c","link":"\/Black-Paintball-Mask-item?id=9254521","id":"9254521","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"543","value":"543","uaid":[33187485,29667716,29603440],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Your Head, a Marshmallow Floating in Hot Chocolate","image":"http:\/\/t1.rbxcdn.com\/c06fb0ee32bc7a1fffa0809eaee66e61","link":"\/Your-Head-a-Marshmallow-Floating-in-Hot-Chocolate-item?id=19395368","id":"19395368","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"510","value":"510","uaid":[150173168],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Tixsplosion","image":"http:\/\/t4.rbxcdn.com\/20829dba1f93f846ca59b669c384829f","link":"\/Tixsplosion-item?id=6512277","id":"6512277","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"504","value":"504","uaid":[19119752,19102247,19103142,19104606],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Cool Snowman Head","image":"http:\/\/t2.rbxcdn.com\/8071c4639889ade76bcdedc3a9e9dd19","link":"\/Cool-Snowman-Head-item?id=5832475","id":"5832475","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"499","value":"499","uaid":[17272992,18706598],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Turkey\'s Vengeance Sword","image":"http:\/\/t6.rbxcdn.com\/7beafca5648a20acfb38e3bd106ae134","link":"\/Turkeys-Vengeance-Sword-item?id=65969704","id":"65969704","serial":[1124],"serialcount":1500,"rap":"377","value":"377","uaid":[739975432],"type":1,"demand":-1},{"name":"Thought Fortress","image":"http:\/\/t1.rbxcdn.com\/f6e3ed0037e9f1496f9030f762e1717a","link":"\/Thought-Fortress-item?id=6548058","id":"6548058","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"361","value":"361","uaid":[19282149],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Annoying Elf: Finsurf","image":"http:\/\/t2.rbxcdn.com\/3f4305d70878fdb390f0a79c9922f293","link":"\/Annoying-Elf-Finsurf-item?id=67798397","id":"67798397","serial":[1007],"serialcount":2011,"rap":"308","value":"308","uaid":[766659385],"type":1,"demand":-1},{"name":"Racing Helmet","image":"http:\/\/t2.rbxcdn.com\/da455ee0b1b27ecb823346b17fd5e59f","link":"\/Racing-Helmet-item?id=6379764","id":"6379764","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"274","value":"274","uaid":[18531100],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Sk9r Boi","image":"http:\/\/t6.rbxcdn.com\/f42da6174bbd7465c0445ddc0b831018","link":"\/Sk9r-Boi-item?id=16412796","id":"16412796","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"253","value":"253","uaid":[424151666],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Mysterious Witch Pumpkin","image":"http:\/\/t1.rbxcdn.com\/ec2bb1a662c370c27338224309acd12b","link":"\/Mysterious-Witch-Pumpkin-item?id=313544522","id":"313544522","serial":[1871],"serialcount":2500,"rap":"244","value":"244","uaid":[2988731974],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"2014 Shades","image":"http:\/\/t3.rbxcdn.com\/19a0efcd98b1b0c46f260d295f8267d9","link":"\/2014-Shades-item?id=140469106","id":"140469106","serial":[1034],"serialcount":2014,"rap":"238","value":"238","uaid":[1645721318],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Steampunk Tricorn","image":"http:\/\/t6.rbxcdn.com\/ce534efedf3f74cc0e536b15b2a81a1d","link":"\/Steampunk-Tricorn-item?id=215718576","id":"215718576","serial":[1012],"serialcount":2000,"rap":"223","value":"223","uaid":[2395346229],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Slimy Eye Ball Top Hat","image":"http:\/\/t1.rbxcdn.com\/e4c9087fab69a9ea572624bcfbddfdab","link":"\/Slimy-Eye-Ball-Top-Hat-item?id=182774977","id":"182774977","serial":[2597],"serialcount":5000,"rap":"210","value":"210","uaid":[2106409006],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Turkey Tie 2012","image":"http:\/\/t7.rbxcdn.com\/2c3bdc43ad85630730f9165a559177e0","link":"\/Turkey-Tie-2012-item?id=98421766","id":"98421766","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"210","value":"210","uaid":[1137346603],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Pumpkin Pi","image":"http:\/\/t6.rbxcdn.com\/810d9cf7b96efa1d62991801eaebee93","link":"\/Pumpkin-Pi-item?id=16986805","id":"16986805","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"176","value":"176","uaid":[189888097],"type":1,"demand":-1},{"name":"Magic Wizard Owl","image":"http:\/\/t6.rbxcdn.com\/626d2b5fedb698324f22f9a294940b4a","link":"\/Magic-Wizard-Owl-item?id=315550913","id":"315550913","serial":[477,931,1482],"serialcount":3000,"rap":"170","value":"170","uaid":[3006772139,3006784599,3006824769],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Summertime 2009 R&R&R","image":"http:\/\/t3.rbxcdn.com\/3ff980e7298051214c725331af9ee51d","link":"\/Summertime-2009-R-R-R-item?id=13334984","id":"13334984","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"165","value":"165","uaid":[49133256],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Shooting Star 2014","image":"http:\/\/t0.rbxcdn.com\/4c082e32dc4b9b8bec98b58d927eb1ff","link":"\/Shooting-Star-2014-item?id=161211433","id":"161211433","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"153","value":"153","uaid":[1871290794],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Monster Bowtie","image":"http:\/\/t5.rbxcdn.com\/b39cb4e24907a7309675e625f692f60e","link":"\/Monster-Bowtie-item?id=315549086","id":"315549086","serial":[387,748,1295,2330],"serialcount":2500,"rap":"143","value":"143","uaid":[3006934392,3006807608,3006810854,3006844776],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Fiery Egg of Egg Testing","image":"http:\/\/t3.rbxcdn.com\/72c8a089ebb7a6c8c4bc8327a4647b5c","link":"\/Fiery-Egg-of-Egg-Testing-item?id=27345567","id":"27345567","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"138","value":"138","uaid":[327610090,327755708,328533667],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Vicious Egg of Singularity","image":"http:\/\/t2.rbxcdn.com\/c71367af39b74980fca6130728c91faf","link":"\/Vicious-Egg-of-Singularity-item?id=24826853","id":"24826853","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"137","value":"137","uaid":[328459317],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Breakfast Shades","image":"http:\/\/t5.rbxcdn.com\/01e027f6a33e96c8890298f6b89c6766","link":"\/Breakfast-Shades-item?id=273965627","id":"273965627","serial":[813],"serialcount":5000,"rap":"135","value":"135","uaid":[2757300158],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Wanwood Visor","image":"http:\/\/t5.rbxcdn.com\/ba562b07ebd270646cce6e18516f9e66","link":"\/Wanwood-Visor-item?id=168167114","id":"168167114","serial":[5202],"serialcount":10000,"rap":"133","value":"133","uaid":[1941682853],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Starry Egg of the Wild Ride","image":"http:\/\/t7.rbxcdn.com\/de40c8993988e5a0afaf6eaca4a617f6","link":"\/Starry-Egg-of-the-Wild-Ride-item?id=31151864","id":"31151864","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"131","value":"131","uaid":[328265480,328398734,327760350,335477398,335436141,332296573,329771448],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Purple Steampunk Robin Hood","image":"http:\/\/t2.rbxcdn.com\/38a18019bae8e052175a341f75e40e42","link":"\/Purple-Steampunk-Robin-Hood-item?id=244160118","id":"244160118","serial":[2539,2732,5632,7472],"serialcount":10000,"rap":"129","value":"129","uaid":[2594827408,2594695995,2594691806,2594775568],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Apple Pie","image":"http:\/\/t1.rbxcdn.com\/d1db205cb18794078ba422ddd339a297","link":"\/Apple-Pie-item?id=18426536","id":"18426536","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"121","value":"121","uaid":[696861482,1597176957,1591866437,131141278],"type":1,"demand":-1},{"name":"Riptide","image":"http:\/\/t5.rbxcdn.com\/3660ae844b6e48c7cd310f77ca9f05b5","link":"\/Riptide-item?id=124472052","id":"124472052","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"119","value":"119","uaid":[1613655322,1459322629,1459513582,1467771990,1470373285,1472650839,1472875436,1476910004,1476911228,1476912283,1478076069,1605005542,1605716047,1611292449,1612258097,1613030058,1613448919,1476905748],"type":1,"demand":-1},{"name":"Valentine\'s Day 2011 Cap","image":"http:\/\/t6.rbxcdn.com\/b86e74e0d2841fdb427c8dc07b710289","link":"\/Valentines-Day-2011-Cap-item?id=46138556","id":"46138556","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"117","value":"117","uaid":[488489253,488399215],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"POW! To the Moon! Egg","image":"http:\/\/t6.rbxcdn.com\/30e01526803b321ed85cb94ac08b7ef2","link":"\/POW-To-the-Moon-Egg-item?id=24826737","id":"24826737","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"114","value":"114","uaid":[332253758,335427281],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"St. Patrick\'s Day 2012","image":"http:\/\/t6.rbxcdn.com\/415093d37f786c144287bed2d3ea5316","link":"\/St-Patricks-Day-2012-item?id=74939534","id":"74939534","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"114","value":"114","uaid":[859518263],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Dreamweaver Faberg\u00e9 Egg","image":"http:\/\/t7.rbxcdn.com\/ed1ba58fd84123529d5475063c577f40","link":"\/Dreamweaver-Faberg-Egg-item?id=102614621","id":"102614621","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"112","value":"112","uaid":[1299066294],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Halloween 2011 Paintball Cap","image":"http:\/\/t7.rbxcdn.com\/d089f3a1dd332257926c91e5dfad9057","link":"\/Halloween-2011-Paintball-Cap-item?id=61847146","id":"61847146","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"111","value":"111","uaid":[733818640,721468555,719776484],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Valentine\'s Day 2012 Cap","image":"http:\/\/t7.rbxcdn.com\/80c0c88c1649090100dc4f4020021bf5","link":"\/Valentines-Day-2012-Cap-item?id=72082097","id":"72082097","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"109","value":"109","uaid":[826615874],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Bolt Biter ","image":"http:\/\/t3.rbxcdn.com\/ecc4395ae166bd1f299a788ba8a47d3d","link":"\/Bolt-Biter-item?id=114385254","id":"114385254","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"108","value":"108","uaid":[1343984340],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Purple Crazy Glasses","image":"http:\/\/t0.rbxcdn.com\/6619c8a71fdaca7c7779383fe7abdf14","link":"\/Purple-Crazy-Glasses-item?id=243854130","id":"243854130","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"108","value":"108","uaid":[2580109584,2580094073,2580046902,2580007872,2579973403,2579967101,2579896153,2579776400,2579771972,2579759337,2579703781,2579674722,2579649571,2579648595,2580115531,2579824768,2580140255,2580350582,2580213356,2600744125,2593639261,2592278398,2589798845,2587450878,2580200366,2583831715,2583315006,2582130959,2581951779,2581731773,2581713334,2584076135,2581367833,2581343147,2581180991,2580884805,2580792186,2580665158,2580587946,2580492313,2580331536,2580411692,2580347551,2581392400],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Bat Tie","image":"http:\/\/t1.rbxcdn.com\/1a68c0b8a7f991c69a402822bd14f8a7","link":"\/Bat-Tie-item?id=63239668","id":"63239668","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"104","value":"104","uaid":[706325495,706337838,706339132,706327073],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Valentine\'s Day Cap 2014","image":"http:\/\/t1.rbxcdn.com\/4c725366cf3456ef00ea41999c08aac8","link":"\/Valentines-Day-Cap-2014-item?id=145834328","id":"145834328","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"102","value":"102","uaid":[1702982968,1704772816,1704655454,1704329398,1704142116,1703837519,1703498997,1703280181,1703027114,1706197010,1702878340,1702871064,1702810459,1702725430,1702705174,1702701882],"type":0,"demand":-1},{"name":"Red Baseball Cap","image":"http:\/\/t2.rbxcdn.com\/e7043f0de498a8d86a0dd3a2f9dda464","link":"\/Red-Baseball-Cap-item?id=1028606","id":"1028606","serial":[],"serialcount":0,"rap":"90","value":"90","uaid":[650588326,799849316,911838756,970599680,1061635619,20390155,1429627843,1689570540,2046428127,9184819,1901694246,2617525148,2201066710,2234239276,2321759816,2355999772,2472984787,2473474879,2474406223,1713281777,2503188546,2476284946,2477624042,2477717806,2493438443,1836184721,1828801218,2484030858,1750266172,2862455261,2631383132,2830069799,2813484524,2699740901,2769611946,2790486081,2771923409,1800268772],"type":0,"demand":-1}],"total_count":189}"""))
```

Comment: I don't think that's the issue here as it works on the online IDE.

Comment: Give it a shot because I tried your code and I got a syntax error. Then I escaped the single quotes and it worked...

Comment: What's the python version on your IDE?

Comment: As stated in the title: Python 3.5, I even tried uninstalling and reinstalling other versions (2.7, 3.4, 3.5)